# How to show one UIAlertController after the other in Swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I want to show user a message once.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            let defaultsDatafirstTrue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if let  _ = defaultsDatafirstTrue.stringForKey("firstTrue") {
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You can add road markers just do long press on the Map", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
                defaultsDatafirstTrue.setObject("true", forKey: "firstTrue")
            }
   }
```

But I have error `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7c2a8000> on <****: 0x7d193800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` Because at the first run the iOS app displays a warning to the user that will use the location determination.
How can I see my message after the system message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code from `viewDidAppear:` not from `viewWillAppear:`.

The problem with `viewWillAppear:` is that it is called before the view is actually visible, so you cannot present another view from it yet. Also, `viewWillAppear:` can be actually called multiple times and then cancelled (e.g. for interactive transitions).